# Update dates in table product

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have table `product`,

An article can be present on several listings over the same period (or a few days later)

I need to update correctly the start date
-identify duplicate listings and remove duplicates

-recover the oldest listing (depending on the start date)

-update start date and end date of overlapping listinng

For example:

```
Listing    article    site    start date  end date 
L1           A1         001     01/01/2020   25/02/2020
L2           A2         001     15/02/2020   31/03/2020
```

expected result

```
Listing  article    site    start date  end date 
L1         A1         001     01/01/2020   25/02/2020
L2         A2         001     26/02/2020   31/03/2020
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL Updating current row to next row's value issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502385/t-sql-updating-current-row-to-next-rows-value-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the end date is accurate, you can use that:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             lag(end_date) over (partition by site order by end_date) as prev_end_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set start_date = dateadd(day, 1, prev_end_date)
    where start_date <> dateadd(day, 1, prev_end_date) and
          prev_end_date is not null;
```

There may be some very complicated cases where the earliest end date is not the earliest start date, but that is not the case for your sample data.

Comment: @csharp . . . Yes.  And in SQL Server, you can even update the CTE (as this example shows).  Updatable CTEs, updatable views, and subqueries are all pretty much the same thing.